# Запрет кэширования

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Имеется клиентское приложение, которое подгружает с удаленного сервера javascript следующим образом:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.1/ind.php"></script>
```

В ind.php прописан сценарий, который посылает разные JS скрипты. Проблема в том, что клиент сохраняет первый скрипт и в последствии использует только его. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы каждый раз посылался серверу новый запрос.
Пробовал запретить следующим образом:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Не помогло.
Вроде можно как-то генерировать случайные запросы... Но не совсем понимаю как.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: нет, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Если по простому то можно постоянно грузить новый скрипт :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.1/ind.php?v={$time}"></script>
```

так браузер будет постоянно тянуть новый скрипт .

Comment: Не очень понял, так и писать? Или time это переменная и нужно идентифицировать ее?

Comment: Идентифицировать , в зависимости от того времени сколько вам нужно время жизни каша. А если он вообще не нужен то тупо туда  time()